# How to create M2 module which filters by custom product attribute?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, catalog

Experimenting with Magento EE 2.1.7 and creating modules. I've created an attribute by the name of "brand" and have assigned a few products with brand data so that I can filter them by brand name/value.

I've created the boilerplate M2 module code and can confirm it's registered and loading. I'm attempting to extend \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer so here is the code and file I'm modifying:

File: app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Magento/Catalog/Layer.php

Code:

```
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Magento\Catalog;


class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer {

    public function afterGetProductCollection($subject, $collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'Ryobi'));

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

With the above code I'm attempting to filter my custom product attribute "brand" with the value "Ryobi". Is this the correct approach for customer product attributes?

Comment: You want to filter product collection based on custo attribute, right?

Comment: That is correct @DhirenVasoya

Comment: you want this every time when category page is load? Or it is based on some opetion selection?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya For now, every time would be ideal.

Comment: As a magento 2 standard code, you need to create Plugin for above function and you can used code :  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('brand', array('eq' => 'Ryobi'));

Answer (score 0):

You need to take not a Brand name, but it's id. Also it's called 'manufacturer'. Do something like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 1));
```